# CSS general sibling combinator (~) not working with negation pseudo-class (:not)

Tags: css

I have a contact list that is generated as an unordered list with HTML5 `data` attributes assigned to each list item. The values of the `data` attributes are single letters for alphabetizing purposes. I have no control over the markup that is generated, but I need to insert a section title before the first entry for each letter. This I hope to achieve with the `:before` pseudo-element. Nothing out of the ordinary. I have a lot of freedom with the CSS selectors I choose, because this project only supports IE9+.

Example markup:

```
<ul>
    <li data-name="a"> ... </li>
    <li data-name="a"> ... </li>
    <li data-name="a"> ... </li>

    <li data-name="z"> ... </li>
    <li data-name="z"> ... </li>
    <li data-name="z"> ... </li>
</ul>
```

Example CSS:

```
li:not([data-name="a"] ~ [data-name="a"]):before { ... }
```

Unfortunately this selector does not work and I am not entirely sure why not, because if I break it into sections, everything is just dandy.

The general sibling combinator works fine on its own, as does the negation pseudo-class, it's just when they're combined that nothing happens.

This also does not work:

```
li:not(li[data-name="a"] ~ li[data-name="a"]):before { ... }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When all else fails, RTFM. I found the answer to my question in the W3 selector specification:

> The negation pseudo-class, :not(X), is a functional notation taking a
>   **simple selector** (excluding the negation pseudo-class itself) as an
>   argument.

and

> A simple selector is either a type selector, universal selector,
>   attribute selector, class selector, ID selector, or pseudo-class.

In other words, it doesn't work because it shouldn't work. The general sibling combinator is not a simple selector, so it cannot be used with the negation pseudo-class.

Links:

1. http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation
2. http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#simple-selectors-dfn

Answer (score 2):

While you've answered your own question, you could always use the adjacent-sibling combinator to discard the `::before` content of elements with a `data-name` attribute equal to their previous sibling (though it's clumsier, unfortunately):

```
li[data-name="a"]::before {
    content: 'a'; /* etc... */
}

li[data-name="a"] + li[data-name="a"]::before {
    content: ''; /* etc... */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/dyGUa/).

Comment: Thank you for the help. I was concerned why this didn't work as expected. My new selectors are:
li:not([data-name="a"]) + li[data-name="b"] (repeat for each letter of the alphabet)
and li:first-child to sort out a.

Comment: You're absolutely welcome; I posted the solution less as an attempt for recognition, more because it seemed too clunky to post as a comment. I'd considered the solution you've used, as a potential suggestion, but discarded it simply because of the use of the negation-class (which I personally try to avoid). It is, in this instance, more concise though.

Comment: Your option is definitely more backwards compatible. I opted for :not purely because I don't need to support IE8. Luxuries! :)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is coming here years later, the accepted answer is not correct. Not sure if it was never correct or if this feature has been added in the 11 years since it was asked, but it certainly is possible now.

Instead of doing:

```css
li:not([data-name="a"] ~ [data-name="a"]):before { ... }
```

You can instead do something like:

```css
:nth-child(1 of li[data-name="a"]):before { ... }
```

```css
li {
  position: relative;
}

:nth-child(1 of li[data-name="a"]):before {
  content: "A Header";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 16px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li data-name="a"> Aardvark </li>
    <li data-name="a"> Abacus </li>
    <li data-name="a"> Apple </li>

    <li data-name="z"> Zebra </li>
    <li data-name="z"> Zenith </li>
    <li data-name="z"> Zoo </li>
</ul>
```